# Given $v, w$ find a matrix $P$ such that $v = Pw$

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups

How can I show that given two non-zero vectors $v, w \in \mathbb{F}_q^2$ there exists a matrix $P \in SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ such that $v = Pw$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split into cases:

**Case 1:** The vectors $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent.

Then they form a basis and we can define a linear transformation $T$ via $T(w) = v$ and $T(v) = -w$.  Now show that the matrix of the transformation $T$ with respect to the standard basis is the matrix $P$ that you're looking for.

**Case 2:** $w = av$ for some $a \in \mathbb F_q$.

Extend $w$ to a basis $\{w, w'\}$ and define $T$ via $T(w) = aw$ and $T(w') = \frac{1}{a}w'$.

Comment: In Case 2. isn't it $T(w)=a^{-1}w$ and $T(w')=aw'$? (a is nonzero follows from that v,w are nonzero)

Answer (score 3):

If $V$ is an invertible matrix whose first column is $v$ and $W$ is an invertible matrix whose first column is $w$, $B = V W^{-1}$ is a matrix such that $B w = v$. Now multiply the second column of $V$ or $W$ by an appropriate factor.